# How do I add classes found in the "extras" folder of QuickDialog?

Tags: ios, xcode, quickdialog

With a recent update, some functionality of QuickDialog such as the QPickerElement was moved out of the main project and into an "extras" folder. What is the right way to add this functionality back into a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took most of the day, but I finally think I have the correct way of doing this. In your project-Prefix.pch file, use the following code:

```
#import <QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h>
#import <Extras/QPickerElement.h> // Add a line like this for each of the extra classes you need
```

Also, make sure that the "User Header Search Paths" value in your target's build settings is set to recursive. If it isn't, you'll get an error saying something like: "QEntryElement not found".

Hope this saves someone else a lot of time.